# AngularJS nested configuration for custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In JSF (i know, yuck, old javaee framework) you can nest configurations for their concept of a directive - say for example:

```
<dataTable>
    <header>
       <column name="firstName" />
       <column name="lastName" />
    </header>
</dataTable>
```

etc.  However, when I create an angular directive, I only have access to the attributes (unless I transclude another directive which must render something.)  Instead, I would simply like to use the xml included to inform the configuration of a single directive.  Is this possible, and where can I find an example?

Comment: can you explain to me what you are trying to do ?I don't understand this part " Instead, I would simply like to use the xml included to inform the configuration of a single directive"

Comment: sure, so in my example the directive would be 'dataTable'.  In that directive js, I want to read all sub tags into an array: so get somehow retrieve sub xml as :  { column [{name: 'firstName'}, {name: 'lastName'}] } so that I can render the dataTable directive.  My example is simple, but I would like the sub xml to be arbitrary.

Comment: what do you want to do with the sub tags ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your directive:

```
    angular.module('app').directive('dataTable', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'E',      
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: "=",

        },
            templateUrl: 'dataTable.html',
            controllerAs: "dataTableCtrl",
            controller: function($scope) {

            }
        };
    });
```

This is your dataTable.html .. you can change the html and render it however you want

```
<div>{{name.firstName}}</div>
<div>{{name.lastName}}</div>
```

if for instance I have an other directive  that i want to use

```
<column name="name.firstName"></column>
<column name="name.lastName"></column>
```

This is how you call your directive

```
<data-table name="name"> </data-table>
```